# JavaScript equivalent of a relative path

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that will be hosted within an existing URL structure. For that reason, I want to make my URLs relative. In an ASP.NET MVC, I would do something like the following:

```
<img src="~/images/logo.png" />
```

From my understanding, the tilde is an ASP.NET MVC thing that gets rendered at runtime. However, I have some JavaScript files that are static. I need them to reference something relatively.

How could I do `~/images/logo.png` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` refers to application root folder

in case your application is not hosted in a sub folder like `http://example.com/mydir/myapp` (in nested virtual directory) then the javascript equivalent will be `/images/logo.png`

Answer (score 0):

The `~` symbol as an ASP.Net feature that is resolved server-side -- Javascript does not know anything about it.  The only way to do this from Javascript, is to target relative to the path where the current file is served.

So if your path structure is like this:

```
Web Application
  Content
    js
      test.js
    images
      logo.png
```

Then, from your "test.js" file, you would reference "logo.png" as `../images/logo.png`.

---

(Technically, you *could* write a dynamic Javascript file with server tags, but that seems like an unnecessary measure just to resolve a relative path.)